# Return Id of each object in my array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects, each object has a unique Id

I want to get the index of each object in the array. I am using angular, but for the purpose of this excercise, I am unable to use $index.

```
$scope.getObjectIndex = function(obj) {
    var theArray = _.flatten($scope.myObjects);
    var index;                              

    //CAN I SEARCH THE ARRAY FOR MY OBJ USING IT'S ID?

    return index;   
}
```

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's an exercice it means that you have to do it by yourself. That's a purpose of an exercice usually ^^ If it's an exercice it's probably explained in your lesson. So reread the manual

Comment: Post complete code, there might be better solution for you, then using `getObjectIndex` at all. For example, if you use ngRepeat.

Comment: Is `obj` exactly the object which index you are looking for? If so, you can use `theArray.indexOf(obj)`. Otherwise you need to loop over `theArray` using `forEach` or plain old for loop.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, I've tried that, but I keep getting -1 as a result.

Comment: @Daft well, it means the object you are trying to find is not in array. :)

Comment: @Daft Post more code, and example of `$scope.myObjects`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko sure enough I was looking at the wrong array the whole time...

Answer (score 1):

if you using ng-repeat for array you have access to index.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.obj">
     <span>{{myCtrl.getObjectIndex(index)}}</span>
</div>
```

and in your controller you can search your obj and get your id:

```
$scope.getObjectIndex=function(index){
    return $scope.myObjects[index].id;
}
```

but if we want to use your solution you can search your array with a for loop like this:

```
$scope.getObjectIndex=function(obj){
   for(var $i=0;$i<$scope.myObjects.length;$i++){
         if(obj.id===$scope.myObjects[$i].id){
             return $i;
         }
   }
}
```